# Bypass Swipe to unlock in Android 5.0.2

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, lock-screens, encryption, device-administrator

I have upgraded my Sony Xperia Z1 from Android 4.4.4 to Android 5.0.2 and now, when the screen is locked, I first have to swipe before I can enter the pattern. When I go to Settings -> Screen Lock, there is an option None, but it is greyed out because of

```
Disabled by administrator, encryption policy, or credential storage
```

What does this mean and how can I change this?

Comment: Are you rooted?

Answer (score 1):

You have set a custom VPN, encrypted your phone or something else that requires a lock screen on your phone. To disable that you will need to decrypt, remove your VPN's to get only a swipe lockscreen back.

On Android Lollipop, Google has added the swipe-up before you can enter your pattern. I don't know why the did that, but they found that usefull.

Hope my answer helps!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have indeed once set up a VPN, but by default I am not connected with it. I find it hard to believe that these two things are related. I have not encrypted my phone (I think).

Comment: @physicalattraction if you are rooted you van remove the lock screen even if you have a vpn.

Comment: What does "rooted" mean? If it is a deliberate action on my side, then I didn't do that.

Comment: @physicalattraction take a look at this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rooting_(Android_OS)

Comment: Thanks! I don't have my phone rooted. Are you saying my phone needs to be rooted to bypass the swipe screen? Seems far fetched to me.

Comment: @physicalattraction Phone definitely needs to be rooted to bypass the swipe but still have the pattern; you must have no VPNs, user-installed certificates etc. to use no lock screen at all.

Answer (score 1):

You need to go to: settings; security; credential storage. And then clear credentials and then you can activate *unlock by swipe*